# Respawn threads on thread exit

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I've this threaded fcgi app that spawns N threads and waits them to finish before exiting

```
#include "vips/vips.h"
#include "vips/vips"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "tiff.h"
#include "tiffio.h"
#include "fastcgi.h"
#include "fcgio.h"
#include "Tokenizer.h"
#include "string.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace vips;

#define THREAD_COUNT 2
static int counts[THREAD_COUNT];

static void *handleFcgi(void *a)
{
    int rc, i, thread_id = (intptr_t)a;
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    FCGX_Request request;
    char *server_name;

    FCGX_InitRequest(&request, 0, 0);
    for (;;)
    {
        static pthread_mutex_t accept_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
        static pthread_mutex_t counts_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

        /* Some platforms require accept() serialization, some don't.. */
        pthread_mutex_lock(&accept_mutex);
        rc = FCGX_Accept_r(&request);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&accept_mutex);

        if (rc < 0 || counts[thread_id] > 5)
            break;

        server_name = FCGX_GetParam("SERVER_NAME", request.envp);

        FCGX_FPrintF(request.out,
                     "Content-type: text/html\r\n"
                     "\r\n"
                     "<title>FastCGI Hello! (multi-threaded C, fcgiapp library)</title>"
                     "<h1>FastCGI Hello! (multi-threaded C, fcgiapp library)</h1>"
                     "Thread %d, Process %ld<p>"
                     "Request counts for %d threads running on host <i>%s</i><p><code>",
                     thread_id, pid, THREAD_COUNT, server_name ? server_name : "?");

        pthread_mutex_lock(&counts_mutex);
        ++counts[thread_id];
        for (i = 0; i < THREAD_COUNT; i++)
            FCGX_FPrintF(request.out, "%5d " , counts[i]);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&counts_mutex);

        FCGX_Finish_r(&request);
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    pthread_t id[THREAD_COUNT];
    FCGX_Init();

    for (i = 0; i < THREAD_COUNT; i++)
        pthread_create(&id[i], NULL, handleFcgi, (void*) i);

    pthread_join(id[0], NULL);
    pthread_join(id[1], NULL);

    return(0);
}
```

I've set the thread to finish after 5 requests for now since later I'll add some custom logic and I want to fully restart the thread after some requests.

I want to spawn a thread each time one exists, is that possible?

Comment: do you really need all those headers? and: prefer C++ headers over C headers (e.g. instead of `stdio.h`, use `cstdio`)

Comment: Those headers are for the image processing I've to do later, since I had the single threaded version working fine now I isolated the multithreading code to ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, you'll have to spawn a new thread if you have let your thread exit.  You cannot restart a thread once it has exited, at that point the system has torn down the thread.  You'll just have to create a new thread or keep the original alive until you don't need it.

Ok, based on what you've just stated, why don't you consider using a thread pool, like boost::threadpool.  This will save you the overhead of spawning new threads at a mad rate, because that is a fairly expensive operation.

A threadpool is basically a pool of threads that the OS has sitting around which can be used for giving work to.  This way,  you never need to create new threads, you don't need to worry much about managing your threads, you just hand them work and get a result.

Comment: Yeah sorry, with restart I meant respawn. I'll edit the question

Comment: +1 - use a pool and some barrier/rendezvous to signal task/s completion.  Create/Start/Join/Terminate is wasteful, inefficient, difficult to manage and, well, just plain bad.  If you have a textbook or page that mentions Join before any other inter-thread comms or synchro mechanism, burn it or delete its bookmark.